# Optimizing SQL Joins: Distinct in Subqueries

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, subquery, distinct

I have looked around and although I feel like my question is basic, I don't see anything that directly addresses it: What effect does using DISTINCT in sub queries have versus specifying it in the final SELECT statement and why?

Given two tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B each with a unique variable and two indexes, INDEX_ONE and INDEX_TWO, and approximately 50 million and 50,000 rows respectively... which usage of DISTINCT is more economical?

```
    SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(A B) LEADING(B A) ALL_ROWS */
     DISTINCT
      INDEX_ONE,
      INDEX_TWO,
      VARIABLE_A,
      VARIABLE_B
    FROM (SELECT 
           INDEX_ONE,
           INDEX_TWO,
           VARIABLE_A
          FROM
           TABLE_A) A
    INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
           INDEX_ONE,
           INDEX_TWO,
           VARIABLE_B
          FROM
           TABLE_B) B
    ON A.INDEX_ONE = B.INDEX_ONE
    AND A.INDEX_TWO = B.INDEX_TWO
```

Or

```
    SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(A B) LEADING(B A) ALL_ROWS */
      INDEX_ONE,
      INDEX_TWO,
      VARIABLE_A,
      VARIABLE_B
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
           INDEX_ONE,
           INDEX_TWO,
           VARIABLE_A
          FROM
           TABLE_A) A
    INNER JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
           INDEX_ONE,
           INDEX_TWO,
           VARIABLE_B
          FROM
           TABLE_B) B
    ON A.INDEX_ONE = B.INDEX_ONE
    AND A.INDEX_TWO = B.INDEX_TWO
```

Also would be interested to know if there is a faster way than those here, and specifically why.

EDIT:
After viewing keiv.fly's comment I'll throw this one in too:

```
    SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(A B) LEADING(B A) ALL_ROWS */
     DISTINCT
      INDEX_ONE,
      INDEX_TWO,
      VARIABLE_A,
      VARIABLE_B
    FROM TABLE A A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON A.INDEX_ONE = B.INDEX_ONE
    AND A.INDEX_TWO = B.INDEX_TWO
```

Comment: Subqueries are bad for performance. If you remove the subqueries it is most likely that there will be no difference as DB will choose the best way according to its knowledge (Statistics and estimated execution time).

Comment: I can write a benchmark for all three variants if this will help you.

Comment: I would hate for you to go through the trouble of all that, I'm looking for a basic heuristic understanding of how each affects the plan. Also, I made the tables simple for this example, but in general would a subquery reducing the column space from say 20 to 3 yield less reduction in time than eliminating the subquery altogether?

Comment: Sub-queries are _not_ necessarily bad for performance @keiv.fly... Oracle will optimize out a lot given half the chance. SQL that doesn't use the database correctly is bad for performance, this might end up being a sub-query.

Comment: I don't know how Oracle works but according to my knowledge subqueries lock execution plan in MySQL and MSSQL. Thus this may significantly degrade performance if that plan is not so good.

Comment: First of all in the example you gave indexes of both tables are useless as no data (records) filtering is done based on index(es) and hash join has being forced/suggested (hint). IMO query #1 is actually same as #3, I see no difference, except of selecting first all data and having them as tmp views for creating the join which might result in some more I/O and mem usage for #1 vs. #3. 
Since you mentioned that VARIABLE_A and VARIABLE_B are unique columns then doing distinct separately as in #2 on each table makes no sense as it will result in same amount of records after DISTINCT.

Comment: Also, even if VARIABLE_A and VARIABLE_B would not be unique, results of queries #1,#3 vs #2 can be different. Having distinct values separately on the tables does not means you'll not get duplicates on result after join.